# How to split pronouns 'whom' and 'whose' into morphs?

Tags: morphology, morphemes, morphological-analysis

Are the endings -m and -se inflectional suffixes?

Answer (score 16):

You could analyze them that way, sure. Perhaps there's an -m morpheme that indicates the accusative case, as seen in who-m, hi-m, the-m.

But I don't think this is a very useful analysis, synchronically. While it did come from an earlier, more productive case-marking suffix, the number of words that show distinct subject and object forms in modern English can be counted on one hand (I, he, she, they, we. Add who depending on your dialect, which does make it a bit difficult to count on one hand).

It seems easier to take these pronoun forms as opaque, indivisible units. The relationship between "we" and "us", or "she" and "her", is entirely arbitrary to a modern learner and will always have to be handled as a special case. Simpler to handle them *all* this way, in my opinion; just encode that "whom" is the surface realization of REL.ANIM.ACC, like how "her" is the surface realization of 3SG.F.ACC, and don't break it down any further.

Comment: Note: yes, I'm ignoring "thou", because while it's still sometimes used for an archaic flavor, native speakers don't generally treat "thou" as nominative and "thee" as accusative. They're used interchangeably.

Comment: Surely not "native" speakers? I'd say that anyone saying "thou" and "thee" today are not doing so because they picked it up from the community, but rather learned it as a learned archaism. 500 years ago that confusion didn't exist (I think), though from what I understand, it did for *you* and *ye*.

Comment: @cmw My impression is that plenty of people learned it as an archaism, but do still think of it as part of the language.

Comment: _Whom_ is no longer a case form in modern English. A large proportion (perhaps a majority) of English speakers now either ignore it, or use it as a formal version of _who_ (rather than an accusative version -- putative case is irrelevant). "Correct usage" is frequently invoked, but is more honoured in the breach than the observance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there are still Quaker "native English speakers" who use "thou" and "thee" in everyday speach, but without respecting the historic case system.

Comment: @jlawler It’s still a case form (often optional) to _some_ speakers, though, so you can’t really say it’s no longer a case form “in modern English”. For most speakers, true, but not for the entirety of the language.

Comment: @cmw some older speakers of Yorkshire & Lancashire English still use thee & thou as subject and object, but these days it's a sign of very strong and old-fashioned regional speech, so there probably aren't many speakers who've acquired it natively in their normal speech in the past few decades

Comment: You don’t mention _whose_, where of course it makes more sense to see it as an inflectional suffix identical with the Saxon genitive in _’s_ and the possessive pronouns in _-s_  (albeit with a different spelling).

Comment: The status of _whose_ is clearly in flux. It extended to neuter uses long ago, but there still appears to be fuss about its neuter use. Clearly it's a possessive, but that's a novel kind of category too, now that case is gone for most speakers -- the possessive sense has outpaced the human sense of _who_, so adding -Z2 to _who_, a human pronoun, gets a possessive that can also be non-human, and that's noticed. It's interesting that case is more important here, but not with _whom_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would disagree there too. I find the argument that 's is a clitic rather than an affix convincing ((the Queen of England)'s crown, *the Queen's of England crown) and the possessive pronouns can't be broken up the same way. If there's an -s affix marking genitive case, it only appears on the pronouns, and then runs into the same issue as the accusative -m: it appears on only a handful of words and isn't consistent even across those.

Comment: @Draconis True, it is unquestionably a clitic, not an affix. I should have said ‘inflectional clitic’, not ‘inflectional suffix’. (Arguably, there is a _mine’s_, but with a double possessive marker: “Your parents’ house is bigger than mine’s”.)

Comment: I routinely count to 31 on one hand using five fingers and binary (which does take a little practice), and I know you can also count by using your thumb to indicate a phalanx on one of the other fingers, making it pretty easy even without practice to count to 12 (3 on each finger). So that list is not very difficult to count on one hand, even with "whom" included. It just doesn't fit in the common, but wasteful, scheme of "each finger is worth 1".

Comment: @Arthur Even just counting to 12 on one hand is still significantly more difficult than just holding up 1–5 fingers, though (I know of schemes which allow you to count to 800 on one hand, but they’re obviously going to be more complex to master, not to mention understand). More importantly, though, you’d preferably still want others to also understand what number you’re indicating, and virtually all English-speakers will be utterly lost if you point your thumb to the second phalanx in your ring finger to indicate the number 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tey come from Poto-Ind-Euopean accusative ending ***-m/-om*** and genitive ending ***-es/-os*** (according to other reconstructions, ***-osyos***) respectively.
Here is the (singular) declension of the PIE word for father (by Clackson, 2007):

[image]

here is the same for the word for wolf:

[image]

The word for "who" in PIE was ***kʷós*** and declined the same way as the word for wolf.

P.S. Beekes (1995) gives the following declensions for pronouns ***kʷi*** and ***kʷó*** (the later he considers an adjective in origin):

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which is about synchronic analysis of English.

Comment: I agree with TKR. Just because something _was_ morphologically transparent thousands of years ago doesn't mean it still is today.